# Getting an error for my discord economy bot when performing a slash command resulting in it saying"bot is thinking" until i end it

Tags: discord

as the title says im making a currency bot for my discord server following a playlist on YT
when i input the command it shows that the bot is thinking but doesn't do any action and this error below pops up in the terminal.

```
PS C:\Discord Bot> node .
Ready! Logged in as Money Bot#6039
Connected to the database!
Error executing give
Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.deferReply (C:\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:67:46)
    at Object.execute (C:\Discord Bot\commands\give.js:48:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Discord Bot\events\interactionCreate.js:33:7) {
  code: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'
}
```

im trying to allow the users of my server to trade in server currency, here is the code for the /give command

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const profileModel = require("../Models/profileSchema");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("give")
    .setDescription("give coins to another user")
    .addUserOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("user")
        .setDescription("The user you want to give to")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addIntegerOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("amount")
        .setDescription("The amount of coins you want to give")
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinValue(1)
    ),
  async execute(interaction, profileData) {
    const receiveUser = interaction.options.getUser("user");
    const giveAmt = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");

    const { balance } = profileData;

    if (balance < giveAmt) {
      await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
      return await interaction.editReply(
        `You do not have ${giveAmt} coins in your balance`
      );
    }

    await interaction.deferReply();

    const receiveUserData = await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userId: receiveUser.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          balance: giveAmt,
        },
      }
    );

    if (!receiveUserData) {
      await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
      return await interaction.editReply(
        `${receiveUser.username} is not in the currency system`
      );
    }

    await interaction.deferReply();

    await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        userId: interaction.user.id,
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          balance: -giveAmt,
        },
      }
    );

    interaction.editReply(
      `You have donated ${giveAmt} coins to ${receiveUser.username}`
    );
  },
};
```

Comment: I figured it out, nvm!

Comment: you should post what you have found as a self answer so other individuals who may have a similar issue understand how you fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you call `interaction.deferReply`, you are responding to the interaction, which can only be done once. Deferring the reply causes the user of the command to see "Bot is thinking..." as expected. The bot needs to call `interaction.followUp` in order to update the "Bot is thinking..." message with the user's requested content. Otherwise it stays "thinking" forever.